# how to drag image inside frame with jqueryui draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following page: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/

What i want to do is constrain the image inside the frame (so that when you move the image away from borders, it would prevent it). Initially i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/1/

After it not working, i then tried to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/2/

but returning false would just cancel dragging for good for some reason. I just want it to cancel that particular drag action.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array coordinate value for `containment`:

```
$('img').draggable({containment:[x1,y1,x2,y2]})​;
```

In your fiddler example, you can use:

```
$('img').draggable({containment:[-300,-300,0,0]})​;
```

Here's the solution in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/3/

Added explanation as requested:

`x1, y1` is the min `left, top` that your element can be dragged to
`x2, y2` is the max `left, top` that your element can be dragged to

Comment: Hey, is it possible for you to explain what each of the values in the array means? I am currently having a hard time implementing the solution in my app because i can't infer what each of the value means. The documentation just skipped over this part... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Added additional info explaining the coordinate values